# Switching mySQL to local server Access Denied using php script

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost, access-denied

I have been using php scripts to connect with a mySQL database on a remote server and I am trying to switch to using a local server. When I attempt to connect using the script below:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "vinylpsy_singles", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("vinylpsy_singles") or die(mysql_error());

$resultNew = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`"); 

?>
```

And am getting the following error

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'vinylpsy_singles'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chromeSave/thepopz/php/getSingles_11.php on line 2
Access denied for user 'vinylpsy_singles'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Can any one suggest what adjustment I need to make?

Comment: Are you sure that username/password exists on your local MySQL? Also, mysql functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Make sure about all of the permissions for the user `vinylpsy_singles`.

Comment: make sure you have access to database?

Comment: try "127.0.0.1" as hostname - it's the loopback-adress.. maybe your rights-table is not filled very intelligent, so only the user "venylpsy_singles@127.0.0.1" exists, but "venylpsy_singles@localhost" does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as administrator on the SQL-server and run the following command:

```
select * from `mysql`.`user` where `user` = 'vinylpsy_singles'
```

Make sure there is either a line that has "localhost" in the Hosts column or the wildcard %. If neither of those are true then you have to add access to the specific user with a GRANT command. Users in MySQL are "locked" to a specific host (or wildcard).

For full GRANT use the following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'vinylpsy_singles'@'localhost'
```

However this privileges should of course be the same as those you used to have for your old host.

Comment: Hi Magnus, thanks for your response I ran the first line of code you suggested and it didn't return anything. I then ran the second line and the first line again and there was a local host line. My script is however still getting the same error message.

Comment: Okay I removed the password parameter and it's now working. Thanks!

Comment: Look up the GRANT syntax for adding privileges, hosts and passwords to the login. It was hard to write a proper command since I did not know what privileges your old login had. I'm glad it helped :)